# No Collections Found upon submittal of channel:form

Tags: safecracker, low-search, channel-form

I'm getting a "No Collections Found" after submittal of a Channel:Form (safecracker). Googled that phrase + expressionengine and only found the potential of a conflict with Low:Search (installed btw). Is there a known solution?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I already had a look in the code. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug and will be fixed in the next version of Low Search. To fix yourself, open up `/low_search/libraries/Low_search_index.php` (v3.0.2), and look up line #79, which reads:

```
die('No collections found');
```

Change that to:

```
return FALSE;
```

...and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it! Thank you for the help and the great plugins!